# c# application with c++ library System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, dll

I'm having trouble with one very tough dll.
 I'm using side dll to make my windows forms app work with webcam. Application works fine on my PC with VS2012, on my laptop with VS2012, but it doesn't work at all on Windows XP, running on virtual machine. 
 I'm getting JIT message

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '---, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

To prevent many question I'll answer myself:

 **Yes,**  the dll do copy to directory with .exe

 **Yes,**  I did deploy it as "Release"

 **Yes,**  I did compile application as x86 target platform

 **Yes,**  I did compile dll as x86 target platform

 **Yes,**  I did install vcRedist all versions to target Windows XP

 **Yes,**  I did install .NET from 3.0 to 4.0 to target Windows XP

I just can't find out why my computer with Visual Studio can work with that dll, but XP can't.

Comment: not meaning to be dense, but are you saying you are getting a *literal* "---, Version=..." message at runtime? I mean, three dashes, not an assembly name? Methinks some investigation with Process Monitor would be very useful here to identify the module being sought but not found under XP.

Comment: Yeah, I was literal with dll name, it is WebCamLib.dll

Comment: And have you verified that assembly is on the virtual box? If so, then the other suggestions here to try DepWalker (or Process Monitor) is a good next step.

Comment: I've found that these types of errors often make entries in the Application event log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) would be the tool to use to find out which dependency is missing from your DLL and thus prevents XP from loading it.

Did you build your native C++ DLL using the "v110_xp" toolset (the Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP toolset you get with update 1)? If you didn't, there's your problem. By default, C++ code built in VS2012 using the normal v110 compiler configuration generates an executable that will not work on Windows XP, but requires Vista or later.

Comment: Hell yeah, recompiling DLL using v110_xp toolset absolutely did the trick. Sorry for so late response, was installing to many updates. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Note the 'or one of its dependancies' phrase... Thats probably your issue and not the dll it self

Your dll is probably calling some api or using a dll that is not available in XP.

[Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your friend here

Comment: Dependency Walker always shows IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL for any dll i feed him, it kind of useless in this situation